# Mysql not returning correct result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, pdo

I am attempting to retrieve all posts that are active and in category 1. There should be 46 posts but it outputs 4 and the posts are from category 12 not category 1.

```
$cat_id = 1;
$limit = 12;
// Count posts
$count_posts = count_cat_posts($cat_id);
```

This is the count_posts function

```
// Count category posts
    function count_cat_posts($cat_id){

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mjbox_posts WHERE post_active = 1 AND cat_id = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$cat_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $count_posts = count($rows);
        return $count_posts;
    }
```

I store all the posts in an array

```
// Retrieve all active posts in this category and order by lastest first
    $resultarray = retrieve_cat_posts($cat_id, $offset, $limit);
```

This is the function I'm using.

```
// Retrieve active posts
    function retrieve_cat_posts($cat_id, $offset, $limit){


        // Get all the posts
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare(" SELECT  p.post_id, post_year, post_desc, post_title, post_date, img_file_name, p.cat_id
                                FROM    mjbox_posts p
                                JOIN    mjbox_images i
                                ON      i.post_id = p.post_id
                                        AND i.cat_id = p.cat_id
                                        AND i.img_is_thumb = 1
                                        AND post_active = 1
                                        AND p.cat_id = ?
                                ORDER BY post_date
                                DESC
                                LIMIT ?,?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $cat_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);                        
        $stmt->execute();


        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $resultarray[] = $row;
        }

        return $resultarray;
    }
```

I didn't added the offset variable, but it is correct.

I output the posts like this:

```
foreach($resultarray AS $value){
                    $filename = substr($value['img_file_name'],9);
                    $cat_id = $value['cat_id'];
                        // Wraps image, title, category
                        echo '<div class="itemWrap">';
                        // Item Image
                        echo '<a href="post.php?post_id='.$value['post_id'].'" class="itemImageLink"><img class="itemImage" src="create_thumb.func.php?path=img/fs/'.$filename.'&save=0&width=160&height=120" alt="'. stripslashes(stripslashes($value['post_title'])) .'"></a>';
                        // Item Title
                        echo '<div class="itemTitle"><a href="post.php?post_id='.$value['post_id'].'" class="itemTitleLink">' .stripslashes(stripslashes($value['post_title'])). '</a></div>';
                        // Item Category
                        echo '<div class="itemCat"><a href="cat.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'">'. $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id) .'</a></div>';
                        // close itemWrap
                        echo '</div>';
                }
```

The query works when i run it in the mysql query window.
So why is it getting posts from category 12 when the `$cat_id = 1`?

Comment: You aren't using solutions you've been given in the other questions. Why ask then? Nevertheless, this question is again a too localized one. Unfortunately, a Q&A site is not suited for spotting typos in your code.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong in the `retrieve_cat_posts()` function. I think ive narrowed it down to there.

Answer (score -1):

Using JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN in the SELECT query requires at least one image to exist int mjbox_images that matches the criteria stated.

Also this line

```
echo '<div class="itemCat"><a href="cat.php?cat_id='.$cat_id.'">'. $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id) .'</a></div>';
```

is somewhat bizarre, setting variable a value inside an echo statement.